# Date_default_timezone wrong

Tags: php

I was looking for a bug for a real long time.
But now i discovered it, but i cant fix it myself.
Im using the date_default_timezone_set function, and i set it to Europe/Amsterdam. When I echo this:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' => ' . date('e') . ' => ' . date('T');
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());
```

The response i get from this is as follow:
Europe/Amsterdam => Europe/Amsterdam => CEST2015-06-18 05:44:21

As you see no problem, but in fact there is. Because in Amsterdam it is 17:44:21 atm, the date is okay, but the time isn't.

Someone who had this bug before or does someone now how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `h:i:s` is 12/hr format ?

Comment: Have you tried echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); to force a 24-hour date format? Capital H

Answer (score 3):

From the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual:

> ```
> h     12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
> H     24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
> ```

Use `H` instead of `h` in your format string.